# Class cast exception in jersey project?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a jersey rest project and one newbie question. From server side:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
        .entity("no access token found").build());
```

From client side

```
else if (Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()) == Status.NOT_FOUND || Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()) == Status.GONE)
        {
            final VerifyTokenResponse verifyTokenResponse = new VerifyTokenResponse();
            verifyTokenResponse.setError((String) response.getEntity());
            return verifyTokenResponse;
        }
```

Problem is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Why I can't get error string on client side ? Is this correct (String) response.getEntity() for that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `response.readEntity(String.class)` instead of `(String) response.getEntity()`